# Mod bus communication "crc function" C#

Tags: c#, crc, modbus

I try to make a modbus app but I need a little help fit the automatic CRC function.

The problem is: When i try to read the `CRC[1]` and `CRC[0]` to put the contained value at the end of my hex string I get an compilation error.

I use this function for the crc:

```
   #region CRC Computation
   void GetCRC(byte[] comBuffer, ref byte[] CRC)
   {
        //Function expects a modbus message of any length as well as a 2 byte CRC array in which to 
        //return the CRC values:

        ushort CRCFull = 0xFFFF;
        byte CRCHigh = 0xFF, CRCLow = 0xFF;
        char CRCLSB;

        for (int i = 0; i < (comBuffer.Length) - 2; i++)
        {
            CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ comBuffer[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                CRCLSB = (char)(CRCFull & 0x0001);
                CRCFull = (ushort)((CRCFull >> 1) & 0x7FFF);

                if (CRCLSB == 1)
                    CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ 0xA001);
            }
        }
        CRC[1] = CRCHigh = (byte)((CRCFull >> 8) & 0xFF);
        CRC[0] = CRCLow = (byte)(CRCFull & 0xFF);
    }
    #endregion
```

And I want to use CRC [1] and CRC [0] at the end of my string, how can i use in the following code:

```
comPort.Write(newMsg, 0, newMsg.Length, CRC[1], CRC[0]);



case TransmissionType.Hex:
                try
                {
                    //convert the message to byte array
                    byte[] newMsg = HexToByte(msg);
                    //send the message to the port
                    comPort.Write(newMsg, 0, newMsg.Length, CRC[1], CRC[0]);
                    //convert back to hex and display
                    DisplayData(MessageType.Outgoing, ByteToHex(newMsg)+ "\n");

                }
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: when i try to read the CRC[1] and CRC[0] to put the contained value at the end of my hex string get an compilation error. I forgot to mention I'm junior software ing.

Comment: try to shorten your code to the absolute minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem for your question.

Comment: case TransmissionType.Hex:
                    try
                    {
                        //convert the message to byte array
                        byte[] newMsg = HexToByte(msg);
                        //send the message to the port
                        comPort.Write(newMsg, 0, newMsg.Length);
                        //convert back to hex and display
                        DisplayData(MessageType.Outgoing, ByteToHex(newMsg) +   CRC[1] +   CRC[0] + "\n");

                    }

Comment: please edit your question to show the minimal code

Comment: what is the line that has the compilation error?

Comment: comPort.Write(newMsg, 0, newMsg.Length, CRC[1], CRC[0]);